# Monty Hall Simulator

Tags: c++, random

This code compiles and runs, but I don't get the correct percentage for the Monty Hall problem. The answer should be closer to 66% for switching. I cannot find where the problem is. The percentage for staying with the same door is right, but the switching, which includes the switchChoice and the revealedDoor function is giving consistent but incorrect results.

```
int winner(){
    return  (rand() / ( RAND_MAX / 3 ) + 1);
}
int userChoice(){
    return (rand() / ( RAND_MAX / 3 ) + 1);
}
int revealedDoor(int winnerX){  
    if (winnerX == 1){
            return  (2 + rand() % 2);
        }
        else if (winnerX == 2){
            if( ( 3 + rand() % 2) == 4){
                return  1;
            }else{
                return  3;
            }
        }
        else if (winnerX == 3){
            return  (1 + rand() % 2);
        }
    else return winnerX;
}
int switchChoice(int uChoice, int revealedD){
    int newChoice;
    do{
        newChoice =  1 + rand() % 3;
    }while ( uChoice == newChoice || newChoice == revealedD);

    return newChoice;
}
```

Comment: This is too much code for this format; please post a [mcve].

Comment: @BaummitAugen if I just post a snippet you will not be able to see what is wrong

Comment: Your task is to create a short snippet that still reproduces the problem and cut out all the correct stuff. See the link I posted for help on doing this.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you I am new to StackOverflow. The problem is that I don't know where the code is wrong. It compiles and runs, but I am just getting unexpected results.

Comment: That is probably better (I do not quite understand the problem yet). What should `switchChoice` do and what does it do instead? That function is the problem, did I get that correctly?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Are you familiar with the Monty Hall problem? The switchChoice function is to switch the initial choice to the remaining choice.

Comment: Why do you do this `rand()` business in there? The choice when switching is already determined by the initial choice and the revealed door, it is not random. Did you mean to randomly decide whether to switch or not?

Comment: @BaummitAugen because the remaining door is a number between one and three that not the revealed door or the initial door. Do you think that could be causing the error?

Comment: No, I just wondered why you did this. But Paul Evans seems to have found the mistake anyways, if his answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `revealedDoor()` method can return the user's choice!  You need something more like (warning -- quick hack ahead!):

```
int revealedDoor(int winnerX, int uChoice) {
    int ret = uChoice;
    while (ret == uChoice) {
        if (winnerX == 1){
                ret =  (2 + rand() % 2);
            }
            else if (winnerX == 2){
                if( ( 3 + rand() % 2) == 4){
                    ret =  1;
                }else{
                    ret =  3;
                }
            }
            else if (winnerX == 3){
                ret =  (1 + rand() % 2);
            }
        else ret = winnerX;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

and then change your `simulation ()` to only calculate the user choice once, and pass as above:

```
vector<int> simulation (){
    long n, winnerX, uChoice = 0;
    vector<int> choiceCtr;
    choiceCtr.push_back(0);
    choiceCtr.push_back(0);

    cout << "How many times would you like to run the simulation? ";
    cin >> n;
    choiceCtr.push_back(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        winnerX = winner();
        uChoice = userChoice();
        if(decision(switchChoice(uChoice, revealedDoor(winnerX, uChoice)), winnerX)){
            choiceCtr[0]++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(decision(uChoice, winner())){
        choiceCtr[1]++;
    }
    }
    return choiceCtr;
}
```

This gives the results:

```
How many times would you like to run the simulation? 100000
66276
33439
Switching:
-----------------
You won 66276 out of 100000 Which is 66.28 percent.

Staying:
-----------------
You won 33439 out of 100000 Which is 33.44 percent.
```

I'm sure you can come up with a better fix, but this quick hack obviously solves the problem

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the revealed door could have been the users choice. Thank you.

Comment: Then you could accept my answer :)